# Rails environment deployment issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my first Rails app here, and I've been stuck on something since last night.  I'm encountering some weird behaviors I can't explain.

I'm running Rails, Apache, Phusion Passenger, and for the moment, SQLite 3.  (I'll move that over to MySQL shortly.)  Currently this is being hosted on a too-small EC2 slice running Ubuntu Server 11.04 (Natty).

When I visit the address of the EC2 slice in the browser, I get the default Rails 500 notice.  Here's what's weird, though.  When I tail `/log/production.log`, I see the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: offers: SELECT  "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE (code = '') ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0):
```

So, I manually opened up the development database in SQLite3, and saw that table in there.  The **production** database, however, does not have that table.

OK, so I'm getting errors with the production database logged in the production log.  The application has to be running in production mode, right?

That is what's throwing me.  First of all, it's running in development mode on my development machine, and I didn't change any of the files when I deployed it.  Neither did I use any fancy deployment tools to deploy it (which may have switched something without my knowledge) - I just did a simple `git push`.

Furthermore, I added the following to my httdp.conf VirtualHost config:

```
RailsEnv development
```

Also, when I run rails console, I can get the following:

```
irb(main):002:0> Rails.env
=> "development"
```

So, the application really *should* be running in development mode, right?  In fact, it seems to think (partially) that it is, right?

I'm really not sure what's happening here, and I'd really appreciate some expert advice.

Thanks everyone.

**Edit** - A few server reboots later, and now the thing just hangs when I try to view it in a browser.  Also, Apache seems to hang when I try to restart it (hence the server reboots), related problem, or different problem altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this isn't a 100% satisfactory answer for me, but I did two things, and I think I got it working.

First, I re-installed the passenger Apache module.  That may or may not have been necessary.

This was the big thing, though: after I had added the line to httpd.conf to pass the Rails Environment over to Passenger, I believe Apache restarted incorrectly.  (Rather, I believe I've been restarting Apache incorrectly for my whole life!)

I was trying to restart Apache this way:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

That has always worked for me (when programming PHP), but it simply wasn't working here.  Apache would just stall on the restart.

This, however, works fine:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

I'll have to ask Server Fault what the significant difference is between the two.

I hope that helps someone out.